# subdomained Nginx Returns 403 forbidden for unicorn/rails setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, nginx, unicorn

I am trying to route my subdomain to a digital ocean server running a rails app via nginx and unicorn. On some computers, the app loads fine. On others (and most) the site routes to the IP and returns nginx 403 error. It looks like this in the logs of /var/log/nginx/error.log:
    [error] 1618#0: *68 directory index of "path/to/app"             is forbidden, client: 24.114.44.135, server: _,

Here is my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file:

```
user **user**;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
      ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref:     POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json   application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascrip$

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Deployer is the same user I'm (successfully) deploying with capistrano
Here is the result of running ls -la at /var/www:

```
total 16
drwxrwx---  4 deployer deployer 4096 Apr 23 14:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 13      775 www-data 4096 Apr 22 17:30 ..
drwxrwx---  2 deployer deployer 4096 Apr 23 14:40 html
drwxrwxr-x  4 deployer deployer 4096 May  7 20:11 my_app_name
```

subfolders/files all seem to be owned by deployer and is the result of running:

```
chown -R deployer:deployer
```

I also have tried :

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

as suggested by some blogs/other questions..admittedly I'm sort of lost in commands and permissions now. My linux/production experience is pretty weak.
I have a bunch of answers to the similar question including changing config to nginx user www-data and various combinations. The tailing error logs are various forms of *number directory forbidden. This error only started happening after I tried to move it from IP to subdomain.

Edit for /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/appstuff:

```
upstream unicorn_my_app_name_production {
server unix:/tmp/unicorn.my_app_name_production.sock fail_timeout=0;

}



server {
listen 80;


client_max_body_size 4G;
keepalive_timeout 10;
error_page 500 502 504 /500.html;
error_page 503 @503;

server_name sub.domain.com;
root path/to/public/folder;
autoindex on;
try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn_my_app_name_production;
index index.html index.htm;
location @unicorn_my_app_name_production {
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_pass http://unicorn_my_app_name_production;
# limit_req zone=one;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/my_app_name_production.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/my_app_name_production.error.log;
}

location ^~ /assets/ {
gzip_static on;
expires max;
add_header Cache-Control public;
 }

location = /50x.html {
root html;
}
location = /404.html {
root html;
location @503 {
  error_page 405 = /system/maintenance.html;
  if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /system/maintenance.html break;
}
rewrite ^(.*)$ /503.html break;
}

if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|PUT|PATCH|POST|DELETE|OPTIONS)$ ){
 return 405;
}

if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
 return 503;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have posted the wrong part of your nginx config file. There are files in

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

that point to your individual configurations. In these files you should see `server` blocks. Here's a simple example:

```
server {
    server_name sub.domain.com;

    location /images {
        root /var/www
        default_type image/jpeg;
    }
}
```

Of importance is to note that a specific server block's rules apply only when the `server_name` value matches the current request. What you need to do is find the configuration for your current site, and ensure that you have a `server_name` key-value correctly set-up. Then your site should work as before when you were accessing it directly via IP.

Comment: the file I posted is from /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/the_app_in_question...There is also /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default ..is that what you were referring to? The server block was commented it out so I uncommented and added the server line but there wasn't any change. I can still access it from my computer but not from others.

Comment: what sub-domain are you trying to access. When I visit retailers.hangrofficial.com, it redirects me to `45.55.248.166` which is a Windows IIS server.

Comment: Ultimately I just want that url to point to the app at the ip you went to. It's a digital ocean droplet

Comment: hmm, but the site at the IP address is down? So this isn't even related to the nginx config, since the nginx config is just pointing at a broken windows server?

Comment: It's not even a windows server though =/  its running ubuntu? On my laptop and a few others from work we could access the site from the sub.domain.com, but when trying with the others it just pushes them to the IP address and gives the "now classic" nginx 403 fail screen. So at least I know its gotten that far.

Comment: My mistake - the server at retailers.hangrofficial.com is a Windows Server, but it redirects to `45.55.248.166` which is your Ubuntu server. Try removing the `server_name` directive from your nginx config file completely (if it works I can explain why). Then restart nginx like so `sudo service nginx restart`.

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work . I crap-shoot added it in random places and restarted but also to no avail. removing server_name has now also made my computer unable to access. The logs still say directory index of /path/to/route forbidden. If the user is the same as my deploying user and that user supposedly has permissions. I've seen questions where it also needs executing permissions? are there any commands you would try personally?

Comment: `nginx` runs as user `www-data`, so you could try `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/my_app_name`. Not 100% sure if this will work since you mentioned is was working at some point.

Comment: I will do that but I also defined user deployer in my config, should that be changed to www-data like it was originally?

Comment: Yes you don't want Capistrano user to conflict with your nginx user.